# Not recognzing the 'Ei'

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, plot, sympy, integral

I try to calculate the point spread function (PSF) of a circular aperture. I integrate the Huygens integral using sympy package. Then I try to conjugate the result. The PSF can be obtained by multiplying these two. But I get the error:name 'Ei' is not defined. Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as smp
from sympy import conjugate, I
import math
from sympy import Ei


# Define constants in SI units

wavelength = 1e-3# m
radius = 5 #m
aperture_diameter = 5e-1 # m


#Fresnel number
F=(aperture_diameter /2)**2/(wavelength*radius)


#The Huygens integral
r = smp.symbols('r', real=True)
result=smp.integrate(radius /( wavelength)*4*smp.pi*smp.exp(-2*smp.pi*I*r/wavelength)/r).simplify()

#Conjugate the result
resultstar= conjugate(result)

#Define the PSF
PSF=result*resultstar.simplify()

PSF_np=smp.lambdify(r,PSF,'numpy')
r_vals=np.linspace(0,5,100)
y_vals=PSF_np(r_vals)
plt.plot(r_vals,y_vals)
```

Actually the Fresnel number in my case>1 so I cannot use the Fraunhofer approximation for the integral.
I tried to plot this function but I didn't get the result I expected. I think it because this package has limited capacities.
Please help me I am a beginner. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The errors is caused by the fact that numpy has no idea what `Ei` is. This is a case where you can evaluate the expression using sympy (or mpmath maybe), but it is definitely slower. Let's see how to do it:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

r_vals=np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)
y_vals = np.zeros_like(r_vals)
for i, rv in enumerate(r_vals):
    # evaluation may produce complex number: let's remove
    # the imaginary part if it's small
    c = complex(PSF.evalf(subs={r: rv}, chop=True))
    y_vals[i] = c.real if abs(c.imag) < 1e-08 else np.nan

plt.figure()
plt.plot(r_vals, y_vals)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can install and use the [Sympy Plotting Backend module](https://sympy-plot-backends.readthedocs.io/) which is capable of plotting this expression:

```py
from spb import *
plot(PSF, (r, 0, 5))
```